# Double linked list confused

Tags: c++, algorithm, doubly-linked-list

I'm having some trouble in understanding this code. It's working just fine, however I don't understand some parts of it.

The given code is suppossed to add in files to a list.
But the part that I'm confused is

fNext->fPrevious = &aNode

fNext = &aNode

The first part is assigning value to fNext->fPrevious

however isn't the second part writing value of fNext to &Node

In that case shouldn't the value in fNext->fPrevious and fNext be same.

Can someone please explain it to me. I've seen the examples but and I understand the concept of Double linked list but I dont't understand this code.

Also could someone elaborate this part as well

aNode.fPrevious = this.

```
 void DoublyLinkedNode<DataType>::append(Node& aNode)
{
    aNode.fPrevious = this;

    if (fNext != &NIL)
    {
        aNode.fNext = fNext;

        fNext->fPrevious = &aNode;

    }

    fNext = &aNode;   
}
```

The constructor of DoubleLinkedNode goes like this.

```
template<class DataType>
DoublyLinkedNode<DataType>::DoublyLinkedNode(const DataType& aValue)
{
    fValue = aValue;
    fPrevious = &NIL;
    fNext = &NIL;
}
```

Comment: There are many ways to implement doubly linked list.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out but could you explain what's going on in the code please

Comment: what is fnext? Show full code so that one will be able to answer but i think the writer is trying to add a new node between two nodes.

Comment: fNext and Previous are pointers to connect adjacent lists but what I am currently confused about is the difference in between fNext->fPrevious and fNext. 

Both are pointing towards the same thing.

To my understanding the Previous and Next shouldn't be pointing towards the same object however in this case I think it is. 

The code works fine but I'm having some trouble understanding it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what I am currently confused about is the difference in between fNext->fPrevious and fNext. Both are pointing towards the same thing.

No they aren't. Yes, we do set `fNext->fPrevious` to `&aNode`. But after we set `fNext` to `&aNode`, `fNext` is not the node whose `fPrevious` we set, it's `aNode`. So `fNext->fPrevious` is `aNode.fPrevious`, which is `this`, not `aNode`.

Maybe it will help to give all these nodes names, and look at it graphically. Before you call `append`, you have something like this:

```
prev      this          next                   aNode
...   <-- fPrevious <-- fPrevious      NIL <-- fPrevious
fNext --> fNext     --> ...                    fNext     --> NIL
```

So, first you set `aNode.fPrevious` to `this` and `aNode.fNext` to `fNext`, so it's pointing back at `this` and forward at `next`:

```
prev      this          next                   aNode
...   <-- fPrevious <-- fPrevious     this <-- fPrevious
fNext --> fNext     --> ...                    fNext     --> next
```

Then you set `fNext->fPrevious` to `&aNode`. Since `fNext` is currently that `next` node, you're changing `next`'s back-pointer to point at `aNode`:

```
prev      this          aNode         next
...   <-- fPrevious <-- fPrevious <-- fPrevious
fNext --> fNext \       fNext     --> ...
                 -------------------/
```

Notice that at this point, both `this` and `aNode` think that `next` node is their `fNext`.

And finally, we fix that by setting `fNext` to `&aNode`:

```
prev      this          aNode         next
...   <-- fPrevious <-- fPrevious <-- fPrevious
fNext --> fNext     --> fNext     --> ...
```

And now `aNode` is properly inserted into the linked list, between `this` and `next`, and everyone agrees about everything.

Comment: Thanks it helped me understand it although im still bit confused but thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @BinayDhawa It might help to run your code in a debugger, or even an online visualizer like [Python Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#) (despite the name, it handles C++ as well). But pointer-based structures are one of those things you just have to keep banging your head on until suddenly you get that "aha" moment where the abstraction makes sense. It's worth it to keep trying, even if it's not easy.

Comment: Yes I get you,  each time I look at the code I think I get it a little bit more 
Thanks for that diagram, it helped me out a lot